# How do I align an image to the top margin of page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm finishing a webpage using wordpress as a **CMS**. and my client asked me to put an image/button at the very top of the page.aligned to the main navigation menu.

That's OK, I did it but what happened is this:
when I use different screen resolution, the buttons do not stay aligned with the very top of the page

I've tried to use "**Position: fixed**", but with that, the buttons move with the page and I want them to stay at the top of the page and don't scroll along with the page.

How can I do that? Can someone help me? Thanks!!!

```css
.buttons {
  position: absolute;
left: 85%;
z-index:905;
margin-top:0
}
.buttonLang {
  position: relative;
z-index: 910;
     }
.buttonZone {
  position: relative;
z-index: 915;
top: -107px;
left: 100px;
}
.selectLang {
  display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 5px;
right: 0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
#buttonLang:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: /*#2893CC;
*/#FFFFFF;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
padding: 12px 16px;
z-index: 1;
font-family: Calibri;
    }
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
line-height: 200%;
}
```

```html
  </head>
  <body>
<body bgcolor="#E1E1E1">
<div class="buttons">
<div class="buttonLang">
  <div class="dropdown">
<img src="http://www.jourdan.org.br/wp-content/uploads/button-lang.png" alt="" title=""/>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="http://localhost/"><img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/flag-bra.png" width="30"alt="" title=""/> Português</br></a>
     <a href="http://localhost/empresa-esp/"><img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/flag-esp.png" width="30"alt="" title=""/> Español</br></a>
     <a href="http://localhost/company/"><img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/flag-usa.png" width="30"alt="" title=""/> English</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="buttonZone">
  <a href="http://localhost/sgv-zone/"><img src="http://www.jourdan.org.br/wp-content/uploads/button-sgvzone.png" alt="" title=""/></a>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Can you post a link to your website?

Comment: It's just on "localhost" ....=/

Comment: Hey guys! I just uploaded the website to a web server.
It's in here: www.gncshop.com.ar/portal/

as I'm using a fullHD monitor, the buttons appear in the right spot. But if i use a monitor with lower resolution (1366x768), half of the image is hidden in the top-margin


Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.post > .post-content > .wpb_row > .wpb_column {
    position: static;
}
.buttons {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 905;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

However I don't understand why you don't move the buttons HTML into the header. When you resize the browser, the buttons overlap the navigation and this can't be corrected with just a few lines of CSS.

Comment: So did it work? Then it would be great if you accept and upvote my answer, thanks

Comment: Yes!!!! Thanks a lot man!!! 
Now, even if I resize the browser, those two buttons stay align to the top margin


Sorry for all the inconvenience, for the delay in my responce (I fell from a stair yesterday, hahaha... Didn't even saw your answer, just saw it today.) and all the trouble.

Thanks again! You're great! Master of the dark arts of css magic! :P

Comment: Welcome, I am glad that I could help. And thanks for your compliment :-) If you have time and mood maybe you consider to spread the word about the link that I posted at the beginning of my profile? Usually I don't ask but I make an exception ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try `position: absolute;` instead. Also `top: 0px;` should keep it stuck there.

Comment: I've already tried that...

here's what I got:

.buttons {
  position: absolute;
left: 85%;
z-index:905;
margin-top:auto
}

.buttonLang {
  position: relative;
z-index: 910;
     }

.buttonZone {
  position: relative;
z-index: 915;
top: -113px;
left: 100px;
}

Comment: ^ I don't see `.buttons { top: 0px; }` anywhere in that. Try posting a minimal replicable example in your question itself.

Comment: Sorry... I've tried to replicate an example of the page...

Here's the problem: as I'm using wordpress... any code I insert in a post or page starts just below the main navigation

Comment: I tried doing "position: fixed"... but then it scrolls along with the page... but the position, when I'm at the very top of the page is correct... Can I do, somehow, "position: fixed" but make it "static" aligned to the very top of the page? Thanks

Comment: Or make it hide when scrolls down?

Comment: Hey guys! I just uploaded the website to a web server. It's in here: www.gncshop.com.ar/portal/ as I'm using a fullHD monitor, the buttons appear in the right spot. But if i use a monitor with lower resolution (1366x768), half of the image is hidden in the top-margin Thanks

Answer (score 0):

body{position :relative;} .button{position:absolute; top:0px; left:10px;}

Answer (score 0):

Align them to the right instead of left :)

```
.buttons {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%; /* for example, adjust how you need */
    z-index:905;
    margin-top:0
}
```

Comment: It didn't work either. Here's a clear example of my problem. I need those two buttons/images on the right side of the page align to the top of the page, regardless the page resolution or the margin of the page itself....

To get it stuck on the top side of the page, using a "gambiarra" I set the margin of the page content to "-250px"... in fullHD monitors, it's ok. On resolutions like 1366x768, it goes above the top limit. (here in Brazil we use this term "gambiarra" to express a solution of a problem that is not a real solution)

So.... Anyone else?

Comment: what do you mean with "anyone else"?

Comment: To help me too! hahaha, but you can keep trying to help too.... please! :P

Comment: You are very "kind" to people who spend their free time to solve your problem ;-)

Comment: oh man! c'mon! I didn't mean to be rude. I'm sorry if I seem to be regardless about your help, but I'm not. 

I just tried to be, you know, "fun"... here in Brazil we have a strange sense of humor... hehe....


So.... could you help me? yet? Pretty please! :D


IF you say yes
here's a link to a page without "gambiarras".... 
http://www.gncshop.com.ar/portal/sgas-plus-124/

(May God touch your heart with kindness! :P)

those two buttons on the middle of the page are the ones I want to stay align to the top of the page.

thanks again!

Comment: I only see 3 buttons (1 gray and 2 blue) and 2 missing images above to the right

Comment: That's strange! First I was developing at localhost... but when I migrated to my client's server, I used a "find / replace" "magic" to replace all the "localhost" to the server's name. It worked.... for some days... and now all the html codes shows localhost again....

anyway.... I fixed this one page, so I can show you my problem...


http://www.gncshop.com.ar/portal/sgas-plus-124/


thanks again man!
regards!